# Theme a single TextView background color in styles.xml

Tags: android, themes, textview

I have an application that has multiple themes. I have a single TextView who's background needs to change color with each theme, all other TextView's stay their default theme. I created a custom TextView widget and set it to the TextView in my xml layout file.

```
 public class CustomHeaderTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomHeaderTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomHeaderTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)     {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomHeaderTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Layout

```
    <*My Package*.CustomHeaderTextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

How do I access the custom TextView and change the background color within each of my themes in my styles.xml?

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_blue</item>

        // Set here
        <item name="CustomHeaderTextView:backgroundColor">@color/primaryColorDark_blue</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Red" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_red</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_red</item>

        // Set here
        <item name="CustomHeaderTextView:backgroundColor">@color/primaryColorDark_red</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Did you try to set  theme or style in the layout file? You can set via android:style in the layout file where you added thw TextView

Comment: @GuilhermeP, Wont that just hardcode that textview to one specific theme? I need the theme of this textview to be dynamic and change independently from all other textviews in the app, depending on what theme a user has chosen.

Comment: I'll test a code here and I'll share with you... Just let me know if your single text view really should be a CustomTextView. Or, you created the CustomTextView just to have a background different from other regular TextView.... I'm just asking because I think that you don't need to create a CustomTextView only because of this... but I'll test some codes here and I'll share with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way where you can set a different background color for a specific TextView. Also, you will be able to set it according to each theme that you have.

### Solution:

Creating your own attribute custom attribute in attr.xml

Below is the implementation:

### Step 1

First, create a attr.xml file at your res/values folder and insert following content:

**res/values/attr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="customTextViewBackAttributeColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

### Step 2

That attribute that you created should be set with a Color in every theme that you have as below:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Specific Text View Color -->
        <item name="customTextViewBackAttributeColor">@color/color_for_theme_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Red" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Specific Text View Color -->
        <item name="customTextViewBackAttributeColor">@color/color_for_theme_red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### Step 3

Finally, set that attribute as the background color of your custom view.

**Note**

You can set this color as background of your specific TextView. This way, only that TextView will have a different background color (and not the default background color defined in each theme). This way, you don't need to create a CustomView only to have a different Background Color.

**res/layout/activity_layout.xml**

```
<com.pivoto.gui.generic.CustomHeaderTextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:background="?customTextViewBackAttributeColor"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Hello World2!"
    android:background="?customTextViewBackAttributeColor"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Hello World3!"
    android:background="?customTextViewBackAttributeColor"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You are correct, I just created a custom textview because thats what I thought I needed to do to separate it from others. I have other elements in my app that need to work the same way and it looks like this solution will work for those as well. Thank You!