# Colour attribute that applies only to views and not layouts

Tags: android, colors, background-color, android-theme

I am developing an Android app and I have created **two** **themes**, that they can be switched by the user. What I am trying to achieve is to distinguish, vidually,  the views ( TextViews specifically) from the layout they are nested in. I tried different values for the `colorWindowBackground` and `colorBackground`, but it didn't work. In other words, this is what I want to accomplish :[image: From Google authenticator]

In this app (Google authenticator) you can easily distinguish the TextView ( I imagine) that displays the code from the rest of the background. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: I finally found the answer. Check this link for more:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235703/theme-a-single-textview-background-color-in-styles-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Layouts are Views.  They're just Views that can have children.  You wouldn't do this via themes, you'd just put one background color on the layout and one on the views, using android:background in your xml.

Comment: I know I can't do that, but wouldn't this interfere when user switches themes? I mean when the theme changes the layout's color will be the same

Comment: The user can't switch themes. Themes in androids are just a set of defaults applied to views when inflated. Any specific setting on the view overrides the theme, and the theme can't be changed later on. The theme is also something the developer picks, not the user (you pick it on the manifest, at either the application or activity level)