# Android: How do I set a TextView's background to match the theme (preferably in xml)

Tags: android, android-studio

All of my textviews's backgrounds are transparent. This is not very good for readability if the textview will be on top of other items. How do I give my textviews a background, specifically one matching the Day/Night theme?

Example, "TextView" on top of "Time Updated...":
[Overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doe9Y.png)

Example XML Code of a textview:

```xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName" />
```

If it helps to know, the textview will be in a Listview in a ConstraintLayout.

Any help would be great, if I left out details, please ask for them!

Answer (score 0):

They default to whatever theme you are using. If your text views are transparent then it has to do with the theme or appearance lines you are using. You can change the style to a different theme like your day and night. It does not have to match the rest of the app. However, it normally looks better if it does.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the background color in my theme, I tried many attributes, none giving me any results

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235703/theme-a-single-textview-background-color-in-styles-xml
Perhaps this link is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

@style/Theme.AppName  if this is your appTheme than have you set ?

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAppBg</item>
```

If **yes** than you can use **@color/colorAppBg** as your texview Background color

& don't forget to define that color in both UI mode Day/Night

> values-night/colors.xml

> values/colors.xml

Comment: Hello! I don't have any background color set in my themes, and when I try, it doesn't set The background for my text view. Android studio prebuilt me themes for night and day, but not colors, how would I do that?

Comment: you can set colors for both day & night theme for Day - values.xml/colors.xml & For night mode create values-night.xml/colors.xml in res directory

Comment: Creating night mode colors :

colors.xml(night)

right click on values folder > new > value resource file
give name as colors
select night qualifier followed by >> button and press ok

Comment: So, do I make a new color.xml for just night, or also make a new one for day too

Comment: No you only need to create colors file for night one, for day android automatically picks from values.xml/colors.xml & define only those color who are different in night mode others will be taken from values folder

Comment: I will try this in the morning, thanks so much!